# How can you read the data from the database

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

I'm trying to read the email address from the database but its giving me error message Response object error 'ASP 0185 : 8002000e' Missing Default Property. Is it because Response.Write doesn't allow? is there another method i can get the data from the database and store into my variable? Also how do you insert a image on CDO.MESSAGE HTMLBODY i used  tag and doesn't work. Thanks for helping.

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.
```

```html
 DIM objConn, bs, ossql
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Data Source=**"
    ossql = "SELECT email_addr FROM medacist_user WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "' AND health_system_code= '" & strHealth & "' AND facility_code = '"& strFacility & "'"
    Set bs = objConn.Execute(ossql)
   Dim storeEmail
 Response.Write bs("email_addr")
```

Answer (score -1):

bs is considered a record set.  you would build up either an HTML string or a JSON string to pass back to the browser.

```
Set bs = objConn.Execute(ossql)
Dim html = ""
Do While Not bs.EOF
   html = html & bs.Fields(0).Value
Loop
bs.Close

Response.write(html)
```

Comment: I did what you told me and its giving me an error message Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e0c'

Command text was not set for the command object line 40 which is Set bs = objConn.Execute(strQuery)
But then If I changed to bs = objConn.Excute(ossql) its giving me error message Object required: '[string: ""]' line 41 which is Set html = " "

Comment: Sorry, my ASP is very rusty.  I made the edits.  You will need to come up with some HTML to send back to the browser, unless you are just sending the data back in which case you should* send back a JSON object

Comment: thank you for quick reply. I edited the code same as you did. Now when I run the code again. Its giving me another error message @_@ Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'

Expected end of statement

/login/reset_form.asp, line 42 Dim html = " "

Am I suppose to put anything inside the html = " "  ?

Comment: I was able to read the email from the database, but how can I store that email data to asp or html?

Comment: Response.write will stream the variable html back to the browser.  I guess I am having a hard time understanding what it is you are trying to accomplish.  Can you elaborate?